# Expand a function in a here-string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to use the result of a function in some output, and i would like to streamline the script by expanding the function into the here-strings of powershell

```
# instead of
$result = myfunction
"The result is $result"
# syntax that would let me call the function inside the string
"the result is ?myfunction()"
```

I don't see any documentation regarding this behavior but i'd really appreciate having missed it rather than it not existing.

If it is not doable what alternatives do i have?

- "the result is also " myfunction
- ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [subexpression](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_stranger/archive/2013/09/25/powershell-sub-expressions.aspx) for that:

```
"the result is $(myfunction)"
```

Other options are concatenating string and function output:

```
"the result is " + (myfunction)
```

or using the [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx):

```
"the result is {0}" -f (myfunction)
```

Comment: The subexpression is totally the way to go in this case, very elegant and expressive enough that people can read it without stumbling too much. Thanks!